# Can a CFMutableArrayRef store simple integer values?

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays

Can a CFMutableArrayRef store simple integer values? Or must I wrap them like with NSMutableArray (which is basically the same beast at runtime)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CFMutableArray` and its toll-free bridged sibling `NSMutableArray` will only allow a pointer value to be stored inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make instances of NSNumber to hold integer values

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:15]];
```